# Meteor UP to deploy meteor app. Issues with remote DB url?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteorite, mongohq, meteor-up

I'm trying to use Meteor Up: https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up

There is a setting in the config file to set the remote MongoDB URL It looks like this:

```
"env": {
    "PORT": 3000,
    "ROOT_URL": "http://dev.mysite.com",
    "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://MyMongoDBUsername:MyMongoHQPassword@troup.mongohq.com:#####/name_of_my_db"
},

[##.###.###.##] invoking deployment process: FAILED

   -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
    Warning: Permanently added '##.###.###.##' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
    npm WARN package.json http-proxy@1.0.2 No repository field.
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
```

0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
        reverted back to the previous version due to the latest version didn't pick up!
        -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------

```
    > fibers@1.0.1 install /opt/meteor/tmp/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
    > node ./build.js

    `linux-x64-v8-3.14` exists; testing
    Binary is fine; exiting
    fibers@1.0.1 node_modules/fibers
    meteor stop/waiting
    meteor start/running, process 4281
    wait for mongo(5 minutes) to initiaze
    connected
    waiting for 15 secs while app is booting up
    checking for app is booted or not?
    meteor stop/waiting
    meteor start/running, process 4349
```

Does this look like a permissions issue?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you try escaping the `@` as `%40`?

Comment: Turns out I was using the connection string wrong, but that still leaves a deployment error.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to upgrade the version of Node on my server. I discovered this when viewing the mup logs. Spoke with the developer who intends to add support for detecting version of node and accommodating when needed.