# Telescope / Meteor deployment using meteor UP on MongoDB url mup.json configuration

Tags: deployment, meteor

I am new developing Meteor apps and I just set up a Telescope blog which is based in Meteor.

I want to deploy it in my own hosting (a droplet at Digital ocean) using "Meteor Up" but I dont know how to configure the "MONGO_URL" and "MAIL_URL" in the mup.json file.

Everything was set up transparently in local so I have no clue where is the DB and who is the user or the password... Any help or orientation where I should look up?

Here a snippet of my mup.json file:

{
   "env": {
    "PORT": 80,
    "ROOT_URL": "",
    "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://:@:/App",
    "MAIL_URL": "smtp://postmaster%40myapp.mailgun.org:adj87sjhd7s@smtp.mailgun.org:587/"
  },

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786647/meteor-up-deployment-cant-use-meteor-mongo-url), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835709/meteor-up-deployment-to-amazon-ec-ubuntu-14-04-not-working) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22006768/meteor-up-to-deploy-meteor-app-issues-with-remote-db-url) question. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Remove the mongo_url and it will use an internal mongo server.  (I am sure of this)

You will need to apply for a free account at mailgun and use your api key here.

(guessing here) To get started, try eliminating that key as well and you may be fine.

{ "env": { "PORT": 80, "ROOT_URL": "" },